# Kafka streams aggregate throwing Exception

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

this is my Kafka streams code which uses sliding window to sum all the integer data in the time window.

```
public class KafkaWindowingLIS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafkahost:9092");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-windowing-lis");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        Integer uid = 1;
        long tenSeconds = 1000 * 10;

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> dataStream = builder.stream("kafka-windowing-lis");
        KStream<Integer, Integer> integerKStream = dataStream
                .filter((key, val) -> {               //Filter only numbers from Stream
                    try {
                        Integer.parseInt(val);
                        return true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .map((key, val) -> new KeyValue<Integer, Integer>(uid, Integer.parseInt(val)));

        TimeWindowedKStream<Integer, Integer> timeWindowedKStream = integerKStream
                .groupBy((k, v) -> k, Serialized.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Integer()))     //Killed my time
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(tenSeconds));

        timeWindowedKStream.aggregate(
                () -> 0,
                (key, value, aggregate) -> value + aggregate)
                .toStream().print(Printed.toSysOut());


        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
//        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual value type (value type: java.lang.Integer). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawValue(StateSerdes.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.put(MeteredWindowStore.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl$WindowStoreReadWriteDecorator.put(ProcessorContextImpl.java:533)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamWindowAggregate$KStreamWindowAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamWindowAggregate.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:366)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampSerializer.serialize(ValueAndTimestampSerializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.rawValue(StateSerdes.java:192)
    ... 14 more
```

I looked for the solution in various pages, looks like I am missing something in this.
Any inputs would be greatly welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the default serdes to integer serdes and explicitly set up the string serdes only when reading the input topic

Comment: @Anthony, If you have changed in meantime Serializer/Deserializer or Serdes, it is good to change your group name - application.id. You application might serialized message with one serializer and then try to read with not compatible deserializer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you use `aggregate()`, you would need to set the output value serde explicitly via `aggregate(..., Materialized.with(...))`. The output value type *might* be different compare to the input value type and thus the input value serde **cannot** be reused. (Because of Java type erasure, Kafka Streams does not know that the type did actually not change...) Hence, Kafka Streams falls back to the default serde from the configuration.

As an alternative, you could use `reduce()` instead of `aggregate` to fix the problem. In `reduce()` the output type is the same as the input type, and thus the input value serde can be used for the output value.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.
May I know where can I find the standard documentation/resource to learn kafka streams?

Comment: There is many resources: Official Apache Kafka docs: https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/ Confluent docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html -- those should be the best resources. There is also a quite helpful examples repository: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples